# If the probability that the student is successful is $\frac{1}{2}$,then find $p$ and $q.$

Tags: probability

In a Physics paper there are 3 sections $A,B \& C$.Section $A$ is compulsory.Out of sections $B$ and $C$ a student has to attempt any one.Passing in the paper means passing in $A$ and passing in $B$ or $C$.The probability of the student passing in $A,B$ and $C$ are $p,q\&\frac{1}{2}$ respectively.If the probability that the student is successful is $\frac{1}{2}$,then find $p$ and $q.$

---

I found the probability that a student is successful as $p\times(\frac{1}{2}q+\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}).$Equate it to the given probability that the student is successful  $=\frac{1}{2}$.
So $p\times(\frac{1}{2}q+\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$

But i am stuck here,i need a second equation for solving $p$ and $q$,but i could not find it.Please help me.

Comment: What are the chances that the student attempts **both** B & C?

Comment: Why is that needed?He does not have to attempt the both.@copper.hat

Comment: You want probabilities or possibilities?

Comment: I want probabilities,the values of $p$ and $q$.But only this much information is given in the question.@copper.hat

Comment: By the way what is the difference between probability and possibility mathematically,i suppose they are same.

Comment: Suppose all students must attempt exactly one of B,C. Suppose all students attempt B, then we have $p q = {1 \over 2}$, and there are many solutions. Suppose all students attempt C, then we have $p {1 \over 2} = {1 \over 2}$, from which we get $p=1$. And the whole range in between if the student attempts B with probability $\alpha$. I am assuming independence here of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability the student fails is 1/2. Use this to get a second equation.

Comment: Without knowing the probability that a student attempts B, I cannot see how you can solve this problem.